# Angular2 - Open and close mdDialog in Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, angular-material2

I am currently trying to open and close an angular material 2 dialog in one of my unit tests. The opening seems fine, but I spy on a function which should be called after the closing, and it is never called, which I assume happens because the dialog does not close as I wanted it to.

My code which I want to test:

```
openDialog() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open( ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      height: '210px',
      width: '335px',
      disableClose: true
    });
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.title = 'Delete Selected Intents?';
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.content = 'All corresponding data will be deleted';
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.option1 = 'Cancel';
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.option2 = 'Delete';

    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( result => {
      this.afterDialogClose(result);
    });
  }
```

My test so far (which is failing as afterDialogClose is not called as expected):

```
  it('should call afterDialogClose when the dialog closing event triggered', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'afterDialogClose');
    component.openDialog();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    component.dialog.closeAll();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.afterDialogClose).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can force my dialog to close and call the afterDialogClose() function? Thanks!

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @yurzui "Expected spy afterDialogClose to have been called."

Comment: And `2 timer(s) still in the queue.`?

Comment: @yurzui 1 timer(s) stil in the queue, yes

Answer (score 2):

I think the main error is

> 1 timer(s) stil in the queue.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127

To solve it we can use `jasmine.done` instead of `async/fakeAsync`

```
it('should call afterDialogClose when the dialog closing event triggered', (done) => {
  spyOn(component, 'afterDialogClose');
  component.openDialog();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    component.dialog.closeAll();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.afterDialogClose).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/elBgCqk0zGgUlXpRwvcG?p=preview)**

Comment: that fixes the queue error right. But still, the afterDialogClose function is still not called as expected which means the dialog is not closed

Comment: Can you reproduce it in my plunker?